# Google In App BIlling Returns Null Purchases when calling getPurchases

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I had writing an IAB(In App Billing) application . the premium  purchase will be submitted into google dashboard and also I can see the invoice of that item and user cannot buy this item twice. so this is ok.

But  by using code below I cannot understand that the user is premium or not,  because the **premiumPurchase** is always **null**. ( I am calling this method in on setup finished listener)

```
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

                if (mHelper == null) return;

                if (result.isFailure()) {

                    return;
                }


                Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMUIM);

                if(premiumPurchase!=null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"permuim",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    lblIsPremuim.setText("You are Premium");
                }
                else{
                    lblIsPremuim.setText("You are Not Premium");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not permuim",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
});
```

I had restarted the device and clear the cache of Google Play and I am sure that I have signed in with correct account. the base-64 public key is surely correct and I had read all  posts in Stack-Over-Flow which has been mentioned about this issue but not finding a solution. I am using same version name and version code and same key store with uploaded app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some days I had solved the problem by manipulating the AndroidManifest.XML file:

1) I had removed permission below: ( because I had thought that is conflicting with billing permission) , but possibly you can leave this line .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

2) I notified that there is such line in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:maxSdkVersion="9" />
```

So by above statement,  min is more than max version , it is not logical , so I have changed this to below:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

After that I cleaned the project and make a rebuild and also restarting the device.then I can get my all purchases...

**Very Important**
**update : you should sign in sign out from your google store app.**